# How efficient is this hash function?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I am not sure the best way to go about hashing a "dictionary" into a table.

The dictionary has 61406 words, I determine the overload by SizeOFDictionary/.75

That gives me 81874 buckets in the table.

I run it through my hash function(generic random algorithm) and there are 31690 buckets that get used up. and 50 some thousand that are empty. The largest bucket only contains 10 words.

My question: Do these numbers suffice for a hashing project? I am unfamiliar with what I am trying to achieve, to me, it seems like 50 some thousand is a lot of empty buckets.

Here is my hashing function.

```
private void hashingAlgorithm(String word)
{
    int key = 1;
    //Multiplying ASCII values of string
    //To determine the index
    for(int i = 0 ; i < word.length(); i++){
        key *= (int)word.charAt(i);
        //Accounting for integer overflow
        if(key<0)
            key*=-1;
    }
    key %= sizeOfTable;
    //Inserting into the table
    table[key].addToBucket(word);       
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `String.hashCode()`?

Comment: I am supposed to create my own hashing algorithm. This is for a class project.

Comment: OK, this is a hashing algorithm. But it doesn't look very good to me. at least multiply the character value with an integer of your choice and instead of multiplying the key add them to the key and modulo at every step.

Comment: @Fallen, I will do that, can you tell me what the purpose of choosing an integer of my choice?

Comment: 2 * 3 == 3 * 2 but (2*10+3) != (3*10+2) . . .

Answer (score 2):

**Performance analysis:**

Your hashing function doesn't take the order into account. According to your algorithm, if there's no overflow,
`ab = ba`. Your code depends on overflow to make difference between different order. So there is space for a lot of extra collisions which can be removed if you think about the sentences to be a N based number.

**Suggested Improvement:**

`2 * 3 == 3 * 2`
but
`2 * 223 + 3 != 3 * 223 + 2`

So if we represent the strings as N based number, number of collisions will be decreased at a dramatic scale.

Answer (score 1):

If dictionary contains words like :

```
abdc  
abcd  
dbca  
dabc  
dacb
```

all will get hashed to same value in hash table i.e `int(a)*int(b)*int(c)*int(d)` , which is not a good idea .
  So , use rolling hash .

**example**   :
`hash = [0]*base^(n-1) + [1]*base^(n-2) + ... + [n-1]`
where base be a `prime number` like say `31`.

**NOTE** : `[i]` means `char.at(i)` .

you can also use `modulo p` [obviously p is a prime number] operator to avoid `overflow` and limit your `size` of hash table .

`hash = [0]*base^(n-1) + [1]*base^(n-2) + ... + [n-1] mod p`

Comment: key *= (int)word.charAt(i)*BASE^(word.length()-(i-1)); I tried this and now im getting an exception thrown, stateing that array out of bounds -10502

Comment: you need to do this :  `(a + b + c)%mod = a%mod + b%mod + c%mod` and also , since `a*b` can be out of integer range . `(a*b)%mod = (a%mod * b%mod ) %mod` . I thought you were familiar with it , so didn't included it in answer . Also for `a*b` use `long long` .

Comment: what can be the maximum length of word ?

Comment: There is no maximum length of word

Comment: still , a wild guess , because you will need to calculate 31^max. length

Comment: One more question, I have got it down to 38000 empty buckets. How does that fair with 81,000 buckets to begin with and 61 thousand entries? Does that sound like a successful hash or is it not?

Comment: you are confused with loading factor i.e. yours is 81k/61k , mine is 81k/38k , so you may think your values will be distributed evenly (good way) , but not considering the fact that actually this is not the case as i told in my answer (a*b*c*d concept) .  But still , you should probably increase 38k to 50k - 60k , that would give a very uniform distribution , rest depends on how much memory you can afford to allocate !